# Not able to debug an asmx service

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windows-10, asmx

I have 2 solutions both running in VS2013 on Windows 10.

One solution is the client which calls the asmx service located on the same host.

Another solutions is the service it self which I launch in debug mode with debug configured in the web.config.

When I want to step into the call I get the message

> Unable to automatically step into the server. The remote procedure could not be debugged. This usually indicates that debugging has not been enabled on the server

I run the web service on "Local IIS" in debug mode. In the client I tried attaching the process where the web service is running but also no success.

I added the users "IUSR" and "IIS_IUSRS" to the folders of the web service with full permissions.

Any idea what else I can do to make this work ?

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure to understand - you run the asmx web service from the visual studio with "Debug" button and you can't hit the breakpoint upon method execution? Or do you have the service already deployed and you cannot attach to the process? Why would you attach client to the service? You should rather try to attach from the service solution.

Comment: I am running the web service in debug from VS and configured on the "Web" tabsheet to use the "Local IIS". I placed indeed a breakpoint on the method that will be called by the client in the other solution. When I do a call to the web service method from the client running from another VS solution, I can't step in to hit the breakpoint in the other solution.

Comment: And when you run the service from VS, does it attach to the process? 
Is the breakpoint valid (so the symbols are loaded, versions valid etc.)? As far as I understand it doesn't throw any error until you call the method from the client- then the solution for the service returns the mentioned error msg?

Comment: I see in the VS that in the solution explorer the "Windows Internet Explorer" process is launched so I assume it is attached. The breakpoint is valid. Versions valid , do you mean .NET framework ? client is 3.5 and service is 4.5 (but I already updated the clients framework once to 4.5 and that didn't help)

Comment: In the service solution, please put the debug breakpoint on the first line of the method you are trying to step into. This is needed even if you debug from the client.

Comment: I know I have done that.

Comment: Hmm... What happens if you launch the service in the browser (on localhost) and execute this method manually (so ignoring the client for a while)? Does it hit the breakpoint? If you debug it from VS built in host, does the problem persist?

Comment: In the overview where I see all the methods I click on it and get the SOAP description no test form and also no breakpoint is being hit.

Comment: When I use another web service within the running project and click on a method I am able to hit a breakpoint (filled in a form with params for webmethod). The project has several services(.asmx). So I think we can assume that the debug on the service should be working.

Comment: Hard to advise further without having access. What is the authentication chosen for this IIS app? Are you sure compilation debug is set properly while debugging (not asking in VS, but on IIS folder)? By chance - did you update your web service reference in the client?

Comment: Try to refresh your service reference in the client project. Also check your web service url in configs. Maybe URL has changed or some definitions. One thing is sure, if by any chance some serialization fails, nothing will work for asmx services.

Comment: Authentication is anonymous. Debug is correctly set. The IIS virtual directory  folder points to the source code folder of the project(so it is not located under inetpub). I tested another webmethod from that service and it workded fine but also no breakpoint is being hit. To be sure that I am communicating with the correct service I removed the service reference from the client and added it again from the location (http:\\localhost\service...) I don't know why this isn't working. I have debugged services before.

Comment: @thomas I am having this issue, too. Did you find a solution?